# Martingale and Poisson Process: Show $X_{n}$ defines a nonnegative martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

The question:

Let {$W_{n}$} be the sequence of waiting times in a Poisson process of intensity $\lambda = 1$. Show that $ X_{n} = 2^{n}e^{-W_{n}}$ defines a nonnegative martingale.

So I must demonstrate $E[X_{n+1}|X_{1},...,X_{n}] = X_{n}$.

The sequence of waiting times are composed of sojourn times $ S_{n}$ so we can write as   
 $ W_n = S_{0}+ ...+S_{n-1}$.

Now we start from the conditional expectation:

 $ E[X_{n+1}|X_{1},...,X_{n}] = E[2^{n+1}e^{-W_{n+1}}|X_{1},...,X_{n}] 
\\ = E[(2e^{-S_{n}})(2^{n}e^{-W_{n}})|X_{1},...,X_{n}] = X_{n}E[2e^{-S_{n}}] $

At this point the expectation left over looks like an MGF and sojourn times are exponentially distributed, but I don't see how that will disappear to leave $X_{n}$.

Thanks for all your clarifications and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $S$ exponential with parameter $1$ such as the times $S_n$,
$$
\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{-S})=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-x}f_S(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-2x}\mathrm dx=\frac12.
$$

Comment: I see, and this would be a case of the more general equation $ E[g(X)] = \int^{- \infty}_{ \infty} g(x)f(x)dx $ where f(x) is the pdf of the RV X. And in this case the variable change from s to x is just a name change to avoid confusion. Thanks again for helping me rectify my probability understanding.